# How to position the following elements in a box using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have the following code and need to be able to position both elements within the box (#third) that is contained within a container. Please provide code for the positioning of both elements. I need to position the following elements (see the following lines)

```
append('$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$'); and 
append('<label>Filename:</label> <input type="text" name="file"  id="file" />');

<!-- saved from url=(0022) -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest /MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

```
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

//ev.target.id this gives us the id of the symbol being dragged

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    switch(data)
    {

       case("drag8"):

          $('#second').append('$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$');
          $('#container').append('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');
          $('#third').append('$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$');

          $('#third').append('<label>Filename:</label> <input type="text" name="file"  id="file" />');

          break;

       default:
    }
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"second"]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"third"]);

}
</script>


<style>

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
}

#container {
    width: 600px;
    height:1500px
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
}
#first {
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;

}
#second {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top:0;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;

}

#third {

    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    right:430px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

} 

#third .power1{

  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#clear {
    clear: both;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>


<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container">
   <div id="first">
   <span id="drag8" style="text-decoration:overline;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$</span>
    </div>
    <div id="second" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">    </div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do u mean by position. If I am not wrong what you want is to append your values to `<div id="container">`

Comment: @Shubham thanks. If you see the append to display the {t}^x\sqrt{t}^x symbol I want to be able to position the input text box right above the first t so the user can input the power and same for the second t I also want the user to be able to input the power by way of another text input box. The positioning should be cross platform IE Chrome and FF. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Shubham I tried the following code and it still does not work.                      $('#third').append('$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$').css({"font-size","75%" "position", "absolute", "left", "100px", "top", "150px"});

Comment: can you provide a cleaner jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q1q2p8t3/

Comment: @madalin. I'm not sure what you mean jsfiddle ? Would I be allowed to modify the code at the link provided to include the entire HTML code ?

Comment: yes man you can do whatever you want with that code in jsfiddle, but don't forget to save and send back the url with the provided code

Comment: @madalin I've uploaded the entire source code file here:     http://web.ncf.ca/~eh936/Files/MathJax%20Drag%20and%20Drop%20-%20Working%20Code.html

Comment: what exactly do you want to do??

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the 3 appends

```
 $('#container').append('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">$${t}^x\sqrt{t}^x$$<label>Filename:</label> <input type="text" name="file"  id="file" /></div>');
```